# How to count distinct values in a node?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

How to count distinct values in a node in XSLT?

Example: I want to count the number of existing countries in Country nodes, in this case, it would be 3.

```
<Artists_by_Countries>
    <Artist_by_Country>
        <Location_ID>62</Location_ID>
        <Artist_ID>212</Artist_ID>
        <Country>Argentina</Country>
    </Artist_by_Country>
    <Artist_by_Country>
        <Location_ID>4</Location_ID>
        <Artist_ID>108</Artist_ID>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
    </Artist_by_Country>
    <Artist_by_Country>
        <Location_ID>4</Location_ID>
        <Artist_ID>111</Artist_ID>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
    </Artist_by_Country>
    <Artist_by_Country>
        <Location_ID>12</Location_ID>
        <Artist_ID>78</Artist_ID>
        <Country>Germany</Country>
    </Artist_by_Country>
</Artists_by_Countries>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you have a large document, you probably want to use the "Muenchian Method", which is usually used for grouping, to identify the distinct nodes. Declare a key that indexes the things you want to count by the values that are distinct:

```
<xsl:key name="artists-by-country" match="Artist_by_Country" use="Country" />
```

Then you can get the `<Artist_by_Country>` elements that have distinct countries using:

```
/Artists_by_Countries
  /Artist_by_Country
    [generate-id(.) =
     generate-id(key('artists-by-country', Country)[1])]
```

and you can count them by wrapping that in a call to the `count()` function.

Of course in XSLT 2.0, it's as simple as

```
count(distinct-values(/Artists_by_Countries/Artist_by_Country/Country))
```

Comment: My eyes were glazing over the top bunch of lines then i found the nugget at the end

Answer (score 6):

In XSLT 1.0 this isn't obvious, but the following should give you an idea of the requirement:

```
count(//Artist_by_Country[not(Location_ID=preceding-sibling::Artist_by_Country/Location_ID)]/Location_ID)
```

The more elements in your XML the longer this takes, as it checks every single preceding sibling of every single element.

Comment: Not sure about performance, but for XSLT 1.0, this seems like a cleaner solution than requiring the <xsl:key /> element in the top voted solution.

Comment: There are usually at least two ways to skin a cat in XSLT - and which is best will depend on your particular circumstances. xsl:key can be very fast in a good processor on large documents compare to my method above I suspect.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
count(//Country[not(following::Country/text() = text())])
```

"Give me the count of all Country nodes without a following Country with matching text"

The interesting bit of that expression, IMO, is the [following](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp) axis.

You could probably also remove the first `/text()`, and replace the second with `.`

Comment: This will only work if the nodes are sorted and the like Country values are therefore consecutive.

Comment: No, it will always work.  following:: works on the entire document, if there is ANY country after the context one that has the same value, that node will not be counted.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, although the 2.0 option is great for people that can use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the xml generation on the first occurence of a country you could add an attribute to the country node such as distinct='true' flag the country as "used" and not subsequently add the distinct attribute if you come across that country again.

You could then do

```
<xsl:for-each select="Artists_by_Countries/Artist_by_Country/Country[@distinct='true']" />
```